# Alternative UI to Spreadsheet

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, mobile-application

I'm working on a an app that has a large spreadsheet of data - individual and office sales stats to be specific. X number of rows and about 13-14 columns of data. User selects the office to view stats and they are given a spreadsheet view of all the sales rep stats.

Obviously this does not work well with a phone or small tablet. Has anyone had success with a different mobile pattern for displaying spreadsheet?

Comment: What is the user going to use the table for? Are they looking up specific values? Or are they just trying to see overall trends? If it's the latter than consider graphing the data using d3js and just displaying that.

Comment: Ya, pretty much just getting over stats, so like seeing who is selling the most the most, etc. I'm still trying to figure out the exact purpose/goal from my PM. But ya, graphs an stuff sound like a great visual alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft now have Excel itself available on Windows Phone. Perhaps you can get some inspiration on how to display a stripped down version of your spreadsheets from how they are doing it?

The way they are trying to make it work is to strip away all visual noise; hiding menus, fading out the row and column headers, and hiding grid lines completely. Selected cells are indicated minimally with a square around the cell, and the row and column header changing colour.

The whole thing can be panned and zoomed in the normal way.

Here is a screenshot from my phone showing how this version of Excel looks:

[image: My Winphone Excel screenshot]